# Probability of taking at least 2 aces out of a deck of 52 cards

Tags: probability

> In how many ways can you take 5 cards with **at least** 2 aces out of a deck of 52 cards.

The correct answer is supposably $ \binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{3} + \binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{2} + \binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{1} $

but why is it not $\binom{4}{2}\binom{50}{3}$ ?

Comment: Because you have duplicated identical combinations in that solution of yours. For example, you can choose $2$ specific aces out of $4$ aces and then the $2$ other aces out of the remaining $50$, and you can do it in an opposite manner, but you'll get the same $5$ card combination at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is it not $\binom{4}{2}\binom{50}{3}$?

Example:

- Choose $A_1+A_2$ out of $4$ aces, then $A_3+A_4+K_1$ out of the remaining $50$ cards
- Choose $A_3+A_4$ out of $4$ aces, then $A_1+A_2+K_1$ out of the remaining $50$ cards

The $2$ combinations above are identical, yet, your solution counts them as different ones.